# How to start One Activity from Multiple Activities without violating the DRY Principle?

Tags: java, android, dry, code-reuse

I am working on an Android App in which some Activities maybe started from Multiple Activities, I know how to move between Activities using Intents. I am just struggling with how to do code it without violating the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) Principle.

The code is shown below where the code to start the Same Activity from Two different Activities is repeated:

***MainActivity.java*** start ***SignInActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mSignUpButton;
private Button mSignInButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_MainActivity);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSignUpButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    mSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSignUp();
        }
    });
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSignIn();
        }
    });
}

private void startSignUp() {
    Intent signUpIntent = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
    startActivity(signUpIntent);
}

private void startSignIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
    startActivity(signInIntent);
    }    
}
```

***SignUpActivity.java*** start ***SignInActivity.java***

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mSignInButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    mSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSignIn();
        }
    });
}

private void startSignIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
    startActivity(signInIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge about DRY principles but when reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832073/3900842), I get the idea behind DRY principle and when thinking about your question solution I get this idea creating util class that has a method for navigation between activities you want:

```
public class NavigationUtils{
public static void navigate(Context source, Class<?> destination){
            Intent intent = new Intent(source, destination);
            source.startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. I did everything in exactly the same way as you did, I just didn't knew how to access Activity.class in the method parameters. I should have asked about it instead, but now i got it. Thanks once again :D

Answer (score 4):

First-  don't worship DRY.  Its a rule of thumb, not the end all be all of good programming.

Second-  generally what I do for this is

```
class SignInIntent extends Activity {
    public static Intent createIntent(Context context, parameters) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SignInIntent.class);
        //Pass parameters here
        return intent;
    }
}

class SomeOtherActivity extends Activity {
    public void someFunc() {
        startActivity(SignInIntent.createIntent(this, params);
    }
}
```

I generally have it return an intent rather than just start the activity in case they want to wait for some reason.  This way you can also keep all the knowledge of what parameters are needed and their names inside SignInActivity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, can you please tell me what is meant by parameters in createIntent. Actually I was trying something similar but I don't know how to pass Activity.class as parameter.

Comment: You don't need to pass Activity.class as a parameter.  THe parameters are any data you need to insert into the intent for use by the new activity.  For example, lets say SignInActivity takes a URL to redirect to when finished.  Then parameters would be URL redirectUrl.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation @Gabe Sechan, your explanation has made it clear.

Answer (score 1):

One of the good considerations is to have `BaseActivity` that contains common functions.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 


public void startActivity(Class<?> mClass, Bundle extras){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, mClass);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void startActivity(Class<?> mClass){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, mClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}

public class SignUpActivity extends BaseActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    mSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(SignInActivity.class);
        }
    });
  }
}
```